# EF Core avoid loading Parent entity when using Include

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following code

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionOption
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string OptionText { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("QuestionId")]
    public Question Question { get; set; }
    public long QuestionId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionOptionAnswer> QuestionOptionAnswers { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionOptionAnswer
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("QuestionOptionId")]
    public QuestionOption QuestionOption { get; set; }
    public long QuestionOptionId { get; set; }
}
```

and the following query to retrieve the question:

```
var dbResult = await (from question in context.Question.Include(x => x.QuestionOptions).ThenInclude(x => x.QuestionOptionAnswers)
                                  where question.Id == id
                                  select question).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Everything works fine and the query returns what I really need except from the fact that I can see in a QuestionOption the parent Entity(Question) which I already have. I have cases that I have 10 question options for a question and each one has the Question parent entity returned. This is not desired as I am getting the same thing I already have multiple times. How can I prevent this from happening?
[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that? You realized they are all references to the same object right?

Comment: thanks for your reply. Doing what?

Comment: preventing it to load the parent object.

Comment: for performance and costs reasons. e.g more serializations/deserializations between sql server and app more object allocations, more network bandwidth => more costs

Comment: you **must** use DTO objects for serialization purposes. Other than that, there is actually only one parent object and your ide represents it like multiple so you will be fine

Comment: When I said serialization I mean about transfer between sql server and my app. not my app and client. So you are saying that the object is returned only once and that what I see is Visual Studio behavior only?

Comment: Entity framework builds the relation between your objects as per your model. The data (for the question) record is only retrieved once from the database. You will even see that same record even if you query something else (using the same context) that references that Question ID.

Comment: Yes, you don't need to worry about circular references when using EF. You can think VS behaviour just like DateTime presentation.

Comment: Thanks for your support

Answer (score -1):

You aren't getting the parent object multiple times, each parent is returned as a single row from the database and one object is created for each `Question`.

It is referenced in multiple places though, including in your `QuestionOption`, which as little impact on performance.

Comment: this does not provide a solution to prevent loading parent. Therefore not answering the OPs question. So it should be a comment rather than an answer.